# Getting `Cannot mix POST with other methods` error when using `ab -p`

Tags: http, unix, benchmarking, apachebench

I'm using ApacheBench (`ab`) to stress test my site. When I specify a method `-m POST` and some postdata `-p {datafile}`, I get the message

> Cannot mix POST with other methods.

The trouble is that I'm not actually mixing POST with other methods. Here's my full command:

```
ab -m POST -p postdata.txt -n 1000 -c 100 http://example.com/
```

Answer (score 12):

This is due to an idiosyncrasy in the way `ab` handles command-line arguments. When you use `-p` it automatically sets the method to `POST` for you, and this happens before `-m` is parsed. So when it parses `-m`, it sees that the already set method is not null and throws an error. What it *should* do (IMO) is silently ignore the parameter if its value is the same as what's implicitly been set.

Note that everything above also applies when you try to do a `PUT` request; e.g., `ab -m PUT -u putdata.txt`.

So what you *should* do to avoid this error is never specify `-m` when you're using `-p` or `-u`.

(Source: [the `ab.c` source file](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/support/ab.c))